# I am trying to click on link using java webdriver which is generating runtime with some number at the end

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click on link which is generating runtime with some number at the end :

Html code is as below:-

```
<span class="float-left">

   <a href="/Key/Lock/369">
```

**How to use regular expression for xpath?** please help.

It is working for exact no like:-

```
WebElement LockAndEdit = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@href='/key/Lock/370']"));
```

I am trying below code with regular expression at last for any number but not working:-

```
WebElement LockAndEdit = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@href='/key/Lock/\\d+']"));
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to go that far.

An XPath expression like this will work fine:

```
//a[starts-with(@href, '/Key/Lock')]
```

And even a normal CSS selector:

```
a[href^='/Key/Lock']
```

Note, this assumes it is always a number at the end, if it may not be, then it becomes much more difficult.